# How can I get the fully qualified name of the runtime type of a generic parameter in Swift?

Tags: swift, swift2

E.g.,

```
func inject<P, D>(params: P, create: P -> D) {
    let type = String(D)
    // etc.
}
```

The technique above seems to work for *any* Swift type (including protocols), but unfortunately `type` does not contain the module name, just the type itself. In other words, if `D` is `Watusi` and `Watusi` is in the `Zing` module, I want `Zing.Watusi`, not just `Watusi`.

Anyone know how to get the whole enchilada, for *any* Swift type passed as a generic parameter?

Ultimately, the purpose of this is to use the fully qualified type as a key in this [dependency resolver implementation](https://gist.github.com/Revolucent/25daa75bda879dd20bb2).

Note: Anton Bronnikov made an excellent suggestion below. It's one I was aware of, but I should clarify that I need a *public* API for this, otherwise the app will be rejected and my client will be unhappy.

Comment: Have you tried interpolating the type string? i.e. "\\(D.self)"

Comment: Great suggestion! Just tried it and it appears to make no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is `String(reflecting: D.self)`, where `D` is a type.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can get closer to what you want with:

```
func inject<P, D>(params: P, create: P -> D) {
    let type = _stdlib_getDemangledTypeName(D)
    // etc.
}
```

Above will produce almost the string you want except with "unnecessary" `.Type` in the end.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but `_stdlib_getDemangledTypeName` is private API, which means I cannot use it in a shipping app. I need this for more than just debugging.